# python how can I sort a list by a pattern matching with variable names

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have a list of files that can be named differently but will always contain a string of the time the file was created. However, it is not always in the same place.

Example:

```
dir=['test_140815080910_data.p',
'other_test_140815081010_data.p',
'other_test_140815081111_other_data.p']
```

How can I sort the list in order by the #?

Thanks

Comment: `dir` is a defined name, don't use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re` and find blocks of 10 digits, and use that as the first sort key, followed by the string itself, eg:

```
import re

data=['test_140815080910_data.p',
'other_test_140815081010_data.p',
'other_test_140815081111_other_data.p']

data.sort(key=lambda L: (re.findall('\d{10}', L), L))
# ['test_140815080910_data.p', 'other_test_140815081010_data.p', 'other_test_140815081111_other_data.p']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
dir.sort(key=lambda a: re.findall("(\d{1,})", a)[0])
```